# sql server reporting services web url not getting resolved

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed **"sql reporting services in sharepoing integrated mode"** on my SharePoint dev server.I have set the service account for the reporting services to be my admin/farm account .
The configuration was successful and when i tried to access the reporting services url ("_http://servername/ReportServer") , i get only a blank page.
 When i access the reporting services url with local host ("_http://localhost/ReportServer") , i get the reporting services directory page .

Please help me in finding why the url with server name is not resolving as i want to configure the url in my central admin .

Note: I do not have any sharepoint site on my Port 80 . 
When i only specify "_http://servername" , i am getting a default site with IIS Screen.

Comment: Have you made an entry in the host file?

Comment: I have not made any entry in host file but my sharepoint sites are working with server name urls.

Comment: share the topology, sharepoint and ssrs version.

Comment: Its a single server topology with both sharepoint 2010 server and sql server 2008 R2 in the same machine. SSRS product version :10.50.2550.0

Comment: if its 2008R2 out of the box port 80 will be blocked on the firewall, however you mention that you hit the sql server box and get the IIS splash screen?